# Take value row datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

good morning, this time I write to see if you can help me with a problem that I have, summarizing a little make a `datagrid` with filters and groups, the code can see it in the following link, since I followed an example of the page Of Microsoft, with this example I'm all perfect, my problem lies when I double click on a row of the `datagrid` I want to take the id value of the project so that later I open a form with all the data of the project, but at Not being able to capture the id field I can not move forward.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx

I am trying to do it with the following code

```
dataGrid1.SelectedCells(0).Item(1).ToString()
```

That on other occasions I have worked, but this time throws in an error that says:

> No default member was found for type 'Task'

I would be very grateful if you can give me a hand with this problem that I have.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is set or bound to an IEnumerable(Of Task) you could cast the SelectedItem property to a Task object and then access any of its public properties or fields like this:

```
Dim task As Task = CType(dg.SelectedItem, Task)
Dim taskName As String = task.TaskName
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it really helped me a lot, that was just what I was looking for